# Can't Remove Right Border of Last Nav Item

Tags: html, css

I'm testing a nav with a white border between menu items. I want to delete the border after the last menu item. I tried using "li:last-child" but it's not working. I would appreciate if this post didn't get deleted "because of similar posts." If I'm posting here it's obviously because I've tried everything from the similar posts and they didn't work. It's really frustrating for a new user.

[image]

HTML:

```
<nav id="navbar">
        <ul>
       <li><a class="top-nav" id="home" href="#home">Home</a></li>
       <li><a class="top-nav" id="about-me" href="#about-me">About Me</a></li>
       <li><a class="top-nav" id="my-work" href="#my-work">My Work</a></li>
       <li><a class="top-nav" id="contact" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
```

CSS:

```
nav {
    font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: #000033;
    height: 45px;
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: right;
    border-right: 2px solid white;
}

li:last-child {
    border-right: hidden !important;
}

li a {
    color: white;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
li:first-child {
  border-right: hidden;
}
```

instead of this:

```
li:last-child {
  border-right: hidden !important;
}
```

You don't need the `!important` because the first-child pseudo-class follows the [rules of specificity of CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

See [this codepen](https://codepen.io/stephenc224/pen/RwWKpRE)

Answer (score 0):

`li:last-child` is correct (with `border-right-color: transparent;`)
but you have to set `float:right` for `UL` element (not LI )
with `display:inline` for `LI` elements
to keep your display order in the same way than you html code.

```css
nav#navbar {
  font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: #000033;
  height: 45px;
  }
nav#navbar ul {
  float: right;
  list-style-type: none;
  }
nav#navbar ul li {
  display: inline;
  border-right: 2px solid white;
  }
nav#navbar ul li:last-child {
  border-right-color: transparent;
  }
nav#navbar a {
  color: white;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="top-nav" id="home" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a class="top-nav" id="about-me" href="#about-me">About Me</a></li>
    <li><a class="top-nav" id="my-work" href="#my-work">My Work</a></li>
    <li><a class="top-nav" id="contact" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try removing the border-right edge of li and adding this if you have used modern browser:

```
li:not(:first-child) { 
     border-right: 2px solid white;
}
```

if you used IE or IE8 try this:

```
li:first-child {
    border-right: hidden;
}
```